# Performing an action which may return other actions to be performed, concurrently

Tags: haskell, recursion, asynchronous, concurrency

I have a program which, at its core, involves repeatedly performing an action on some value, and based on that action also returning a list of new values to perform that action on. The pure version of my function is:

```
recurse :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> [a]
recurse f a = a : concatMap (recurse f) (f a)
```

Which can be used for things like tree traversals, such as:

```
data Tree a = Node [Tree a] | Leaf a

f (Node ls) = ls
f (Leaf x) = []

recurse f (Node [Leaf 10, Node [Leaf 20, Leaf 3], Leaf 12]) 
  == [Node [..], Leaf 10, Node [..], Leaf 20, Leaf 3, Leaf 12]
```

This function becomes more useful if you generalize it to an arbitrary monad:

```
recurseM :: Monad m => (a -> m [a]) -> a -> m [a]
recurseM f a = do
  xs <- f a
  rests <- mapM (recurseM f) xs
  return $ a : concat rests
```

But what I really want to do with it is make it asynchronous, because (a) I do not care about the order the results come in, and (b) I anticipate the actions themselves taking a while waiting on network operations. Here is my first pass at writing the async implementation (without results) of the above functions:

```
recurseAsync_ :: (a -> IO [a]) -> a -> IO ()
recurseAsync_ f a = do
  xs <- f a
  mapM_ (forkIO . recurseAsync_ f) xs
```

While this works, I'm unfamiliar enough with concurrency in general and in Haskell specifically to be sure that this will actually run all of the code I want in parallel. Also, I'm unsure of how to make this code return the results, but that isn't really the important part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think yours works, but `async` specializes in this stuff.

```
recurseAsync :: (a -> IO [a]) -> a -> IO [a]
recurseAsync f a = do
  xs <- f a
  fmap concat $ mapConcurrently (recurseAsync f) xs
```